# "Todo lo demás" o "Todos los demás"

Tags: uso-de-palabras

I came across this on a programming website:

> Todo lo demás se ejecuta en las dos partes, cliente y servidor.

Shouldn't it be:

> Todos los demás se ejecuta en las dos partes, cliente y servidor.

instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

todo =/= todos, for your given context since "ejecuta" is singular, using todo makes more sense.

One is not the plural of the other.

```
Todo lo demás se ejecuta en las dos partes, cliente y servidor.
```

"**Everything** else is executed in both parts, client and server"

```
Todos los demás se ejecuta en las dos partes, cliente y servidor.
```

"**Everyone** else is executed in both parts, client and server"

in your case you should use **todo**.

Answer (score 4):

*Todo lo demás* refers to an (often abstract) uncountable "rest of". You'd use this if you're talking about something like, say, work, that doesn't normally go in plural in this context, out of you're talking about portions of some single whole (like a single operation).

*Todos los demás* (which would need a plural verb *se ejecutan*) refers to some concrete countable "rest of". So if we're talking about threads, individual processes, operations, you'd use it.

The quick way to check what you'd say in English with "the rest of ____". If it's single, you'll use singular in Spanish; likewise, plural in English, plural in Spanish.  (There are a handful of terms that have different degrees of countability for which this wouldn't work, but they are a negligible amount).